# rails db:migrate error rails aborted

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger

When I tried to rails db:migrate, I got the following error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'MyString' for key 'index_users_on_email': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_email`  ON `users` (`email`)
```

Can someone help me on this, please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you're having a user record with a duplicate `email` called "MyString"(it exists in two records). Since the `email` has an unique index, it can't be duplicate.

Delete the `user` record with the duplicate `email` or update it to a `unique` email and then run

```
rake db:migrate
```